# JS file of hyperledger composer with web service

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am a developer with **hyperledger** composer. I have one question about JavaScript file of hyperledger composer `"What is a JavaScript file of hyperledger composer can use XMLHttpRequest?"`, because I want to use REST API from server in the JS file of hyperledger composer.Or I can use something else to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following script is doing Same Domain Ajax request in the HyperLedger.

You can use almost all the javascript standard code inside the Script file.

see the function `sendrequest` is sending two additional data to the `demo_get2` end point

[image: Ajax request in JS file]

The Ajax is executed the moment i submit a transaction (Because i am calling `sendrequest` inside the [transaction processor function](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/js_scripts) .

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I testing your code with hyperledger composer online tool is work fine but I use it with hyperledger composer locally is show error like this: 'status: 500, message: ReferenceError: identifier 'XMLHttpRequest' undefined'

Comment: Make sure you have the Updated Version.